# What would be an arrow in category of Hilbert space?

Tags: real-analysis, category-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $H,K$ be Hilbert spaces.

Let $S$ be a Hilbert basis for $H$. (Which means that $S$ is orthogonal and the span of $S$ is dense in $H$.)

> For each arrow $S\rightarrow K$, there exists a unique morphism $H\rightarrow K$.

What would be arrow and morphism to make the above statement true?

I think the natural arrow is a function $f:S\rightarrow K$ such that $\langle f(x),f(y)\rangle =\langle x, y \rangle$ and a natural morphism is a linear transformation $T:H\rightarrow K$ such that $\langle f(x),f(y) \rangle = \langle x,y \rangle$. But under this definition, $S$ cannot induce $T$ since $T$ need not be continuous.

Is it possible to define an arrow to make every morphism "bounded"?

Comment: The arrow is a set map and the morphism is a linear operator.

Comment: Compare it with vector spaces, any function defined on a basis extends uniquely to a linear map.

Comment: Well, under your definition, $S$ cannot uniquely induce $T$. If $H$ is infinite dimensional(algebraic dimension), then the cardinal of $S$ can be stricly smaller than the algebraic dimension of $H$.

Comment: Good point I'm too fast here, there should be some continuity condition. You could try to define $T(v)$ by taking a sequence $(v_n)_n$ where each $v_n\in \text{span}(S)$ and $v_n\rightarrow v$, then set $T(v)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}T(v_n)$.

Comment: @Mathematician42 That was what I was trying. That is why I tried to add some properties on "arrows". However, if I assume morphisms to be continuous, I cannot find a condition on $S$ so that it uniquely induces the morphism $T$.

Comment: You definitely need a stronger condition than preserving the inner-product. What happens if you define a 'norm' on $f$ by $\left\|f\right\|=\sup\left\{\left\|f(s)\right\|\mid s\in S\right\}$ and demand that $\left\|f\right\|< \infty$? (Also, I meant $T(v)=\lim_n f(v_n)$ obviously)

Comment: Now I solved this. Inner-product preserving is enough because of "polarization identity".

Comment: But you don't get a bounded operator that way, no?

Comment: We can. If an arrow is inner product preserving, there exists a unique linear transformation $T$ on $span(S)$ such that $(Tx,Ty)=(x,y)$. By polarization identity, $||Tx||=||x||$. Hence, it is continuous. Now we can extend $T$ to the closure of $span(S)$, which is $H$.

Comment: Wow, I had some serious brainfarts here. Now I would like to say that the operator $T$ automatically has norm $1$. This is logical since you demand $f$ to be norm preserving. So maybe you can relax your condition to allow extensions who do not automatically have norm $1$. The last condition I gave you seems interesting in that respect. (But ignore the first sentence in that comment, it's very wrong!)